# Searching a file case insensitive and open it in zsh

Tags: linux, zsh

I'm trying to use zsh in  a more efficient way and therefore I ask for help.

In a script I am searching for a filename, e.g. foo which can be written in upper or lowercase, like:

- foo
- Foo
- FOo

Afterwards I execute a command using the first found filename as an argument.

To to this task I used the following command lines:

```
FILE=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname foo -print -quit) 
command-dummy ${FILE}
```

I'm pretty sure that there exists a more efficient way and asking for advice and maybe a code with *style*.

Comment: A more correct way would be `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname foo -exec command-dummy {} \;` or `for f in [fF][oO][oO]; do [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue; command-dummy "$f"; done`, but you'll better use @chepner pure zsh solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zsh` pathname expansion can handle this without using `find`, if you enable the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option.

```
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
command-dummy (#i)foo(.)
```

`(#i)` (after enabling extended globbing) makes the pattern match case-insensitive, and `(.)` restricts matches to regular files.

See `man zshexpn` for more information.

Comment: I read it in the manual but overlooked #i, tried something with #l but it got to complicated. Thank you for your code with "style" !